# MySQL set AUTO_INCREMENT value to MAX(id) + 1 shortcut?

Tags: mysql

I constantly need to "reset" the AUTO_INCREMENT value of my tables, after I delete a part of my rows. Let me explain with an actual example :

I have a table called `CLIENT`. Let us say before removing some rows, the auto_increment was set to `11`. Then I delete the 4 lasts rows. The auto_increment is still set to 11. So when I will insert some clients again, it will make a hole of id.

I always need to "clean" the auto_increment, e.g. using this function below :

```
function cleanAutoIncrement($tableName, $columnAutoIncrement, $pdo)
{
    $r = false;

    try {
        $p = $pdo->prepare("SELECT IFNULL(MAX($columnAutoIncrement) + 1, 1) AS 'max' FROM $tableName LIMIT 1;");
        $p->execute();

        $max = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['max'];

        $p = $pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE $tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = $max;"):

        $p->execute();

        $r = true;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $r = false;
    }

    return $r;
}
```

What the function do is to get the maximum id in the table, then increments it of 1, and return its value (if there was no rows in table, it return 1). Then I alter the table to reset a "clean" id in order not to let any hole of id.

**QUESTION**

Is there any MySQL command to perform this task without having to do this manually ?

Comment: been asked many times, gaps in sequences isn't a problem worth attending to

Comment: The only way to have MySQL resetting the counter of an auto-increment column in a table is to **truncate** the table (which is not what you want). Secondly, I fully agree with @e4c5. Why would it be important for you to have always the IDs running without gaps?

Comment: What is the reason that you need no gaps between your IDs? as @e4c5 mentioned, it's unavoidable to have no gaps in _auto increment IDs_. if you need such a field, it's better to create another integer field and calculate/generate it manually(which I strongly advise you to avoid it!)

Comment: @FDavidov : No it is not. It only would be to consider leaving this project without thinking of out of range increment value (we add aproximatively 2 millions rows per months, sometimes with "gap" of ten thousands of ids). **EhsanT** For the same reason, leaving the code and be sure everything is quite ok even without me behind the desk. I will follow your advices then, no gap processing.

Answer (score 0):

To close this question, no shortcut exists in MySQL and it is not recommended to perform this task.